# Android studio SDK components?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the picture for this I don't know why it doesn't work
any help, please

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't see any problems. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is stuck in this downloading area.
Some times Android studio takes more time to download according to your internet connection speed.